# Uncheck the first checked CheckBox when count exceeds the Maxlimit

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have a `CheckBoxList` and my requirement is to allow user to select maximum three options(through Javascript) and as soon as he clicks on the fourth one the first selected `CheckBox` gets unchecked, similarly when he selects the fifth (another) one, the `CheckBox` which was selected second, gets unchecked and so on. Eventually user is left with only three selected options.

**Eg.** In the given image if user selects .Net(first),Java(second),PHP(third) and when he selects SQL(fourth), .Net gets unchecked and SQL gets checked. Further when he selects Cloud Computing(fifth), Java gets unchecked.

[image]

I have written the following Javascript which works fine for the first scenario and un- checks the first selected item when fourth one is selected but it doesn't work further because `counter` value again reaches to 4 and `cbArray[counter - 4]` again tries to uncheck the first box instead of second. How to resolve this problem. Thanks.

My **Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function limitChecked(maxCount) {
            debugger;
            var ocbList = document.getElementById('cbList');
            var cbArray = ocbList.getElementsByTagName('input');
            var counter = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < cbArray.length; i++) {
                if (cbArray[i].checked==true) {
                    counter++;
                    if (counter > maxCount) {
                           cbArray[counter - 4].checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```

**.aspx code:**

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Courses:
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbList" runat="server" onclick="limitChecked(3)">
            <asp:ListItem>.Net</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Java</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>PHP</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>SQL</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Cloud Computing</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Add the individual elements to an array as they are checked, once the count is over 4, remove the first element in the array (using the slice method). I'm too lazy to write that out right now, but you get the idea.

Comment: @Trendy Thanks for the input. I'm going to try accordingly.

Comment: No problem, sorry if that was vague, but @McGarnagle provided a sufficient answer as well.

Comment: @Trendy No it was quite clear. Thanks. McGarnagle's answer is performing LIFO instead of FIFO.

Comment: @Trendy Thanks man. As per your suggestion I have written the script, which is working fine. See below, I have posted as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

As per Trendy's suggestion (McGarnagle's answer also helped) I've come up with this solution, which is working fine for me.

```
function limitChecked(maxCount) {
            debugger;
            var ocbList = document.getElementById('cbList');
            var cbArray = ocbList.getElementsByTagName('input');
            var checkedArray = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < cbArray.length; i++) {
                if (cbArray[i].checked == true) {
                    checkedArray.push(i);
                    if (checkedArray.length > maxCount) {
                        checkedArray = checkedArray.slice(0);
                        cbArray[checkedArray[0]].checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use push/pop instead of the counter.  Using `slice(0)` allows you to use an array like a FIFO queue:

```
function limitChecked(maxCount) {
        debugger;
        var ocbList = document.getElementById('cbList');
        var cbArray = ocbList.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var checked = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < cbArray.length; i++) {
            if (cbArray[i].checked==true) {
                checked.push(i);
                if (checked.length > maxCount) {
                    cbArray[checked[0]].checked = false;
                    checked = checked.slice(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm going to try this out.

Comment: I tried this solution but this doesn't allow the user to select the fourth option, while I want to let him select the fourth one and uncheck the first one. Thanks.

Comment: I just performed debugging on this code. Actually it unchecks the last selected (latest) item instead of the first one. Doing LIFO instead FIFO.